# Error: Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected

Tags: vb.net

I get the following error:

> Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected

on the following piece of code:

```vb
Dim listOfMultipliers As New List(Of Double)
For i = 0.2 To 1.5 Step 0.1
    listOfMultipliers.Add(i)
Next
Dim multipliersArray() As Double = listOfMultipliers.ToArray()
myarrey = multipliersArray
```

The error is on the first line and underscores 'double'.  I can't figure out what the problem is. I searched the internet but couldn't find an solution. Is it the case that i am using visual basic 2003 and this code is for an higher framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you have given is already valid, but it uses .NET Generics (i.e. the ability to specify a `List(Of Double)` rather than just an `ArrayList` that accepts `Object`s), which was not added to the .NET framework until version 2.0.  .NET 2.0 was first supported by VB.NET version 8.0, which was included in Visual Studio 2005.

The code you're trying to write won't work on VB2003. Is there a reason you can't use a newer framework? (using Visual Basic 2010 Express, for instance, which is free)

If you're stuck with 2003, you'll have to use `ArrayList`, and cast the items you take out of the list back to a `Double`.

Comment: hey, Thank you. The reason i use version 2003 is because i'm working as an intern at a engeneering office. For them i need to automate a 3D CAD program with visual basic. The only visual basic they had was this version.

Comment: In that case, you're probably stuck with it. Assuming they don't want to upgrade (and I don't blame them) you'll have to be very careful with code snippets and solutions you find online, since most of them will probably be for VB8 and above, since it's been around for 7+ years).

Comment: Note that when reading Microsoft's MSDN documentation, you can choose the target framework in the Other Versions link (just below the main title) and choose Framework 1.1 to make sure you're seeing the docs for your version.